# POWER BI Plus function wrong values

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem on adding some values to formula.

The straight formula has no problem but if I try to add 100 to the formula value it returns strange data.

Formula works Correctly:

[image]

If I add + 100 to it, the values are strange:

[image]